# Finding maximum, what if there are more than 1 maximum values?

Tags: mysql, sql

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PhwNq.jpg)

So I have written this query as the answer but want to ask if it is correct? If not, what other ways can I answer this question with? and logic for the answer? Thanks.

Query:

```
SELECT email, friend_count
FROM users
WHERE friend_count = (SELECT MAX(friend_count) FROM users);
```

Comment: As per the question guide, please do not post images of code, data, error messages, etc. - copy or type the text into the question. Please reserve the use of images for diagrams or demonstrating rendering bugs, things that are impossible to describe accurately via text.

Comment: If there be more than one record tied for the same friend count, then your query as above would already be capturing all such ties.

Comment: Is it correct? Does it return the results you expect?

Comment: It is better to use the subquery in FROM clause, not in WHERE.